# When is the centripetal force the biggest?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

In a circle motion, where two objects have the same orbital times, but different radius, which one will have the biggest centripetal/centrifugal force? The outer or the inner one?

Comment: Hint: $a = \omega^{2} r$ and $\omega = 2\pi/T$

Comment: Hint: both are rotate around the center of mass

Comment: @K_inverse so it increases as the radius increases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{F_{c1}}{F_{c2}} = \frac{mr_1\omega_1^2}{mr_2\omega_2^2} $$ and
$ \omega_1 = \omega_2 $, because $ \omega = \frac{2\pi}{T} $, and $T=const$ according task conditions, so
$$ \frac{F_{c1}}{F_{c2}} = \frac{r_1}{r_2} $$
given that $ r_1 > r_2$, we get $$ \frac{F_{c1}}{F_{c2}} > 1 $$, thus increasing radius while keeping angular speed the same - increases centripetal force

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming:

1. there is some force which act towards Centre for both of the masses,
2. $F= m \omega^{2} r,$  $\omega=2\pi/T.$

Simple, clear: the more radius, greater the centripetal acceleration.  Assume $w$ to be constant.